# Auto-adjustment of length(size) of bar of substitution

Tags: substitution

Wrote below.

```tex
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \left(\exp\left(x\right)^{\left(i\right)}\right)|_{x=0}
  =\exp\left(x\right)|_{x=0}=1$\\\\
\end{document}
```

Got the following.

[image]

I want to know the notation which enable auto-adjust of length(size) of bar of substitution of variable.

So, in this case, the first expression of substitution is a problem for me .

The length of the bar has should be more long.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: The two [!] occurrences of `\exp\left(x\right)`, while not syntactic errors, are nevertheless *first-order typographic blunders*. Why? The `\left(` instruction ends up inserting unnecessary and unwanted whitespace between `exp` and `(x)`,  while not actually changing the *size* of the parentheses. Please don't over-use `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: I used snippet to write that exp function ,without thinking your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on `\left` and `\right` for the formula you show, as it chooses too big delimiters.

Closely compare (3) and (5) in the picture below and judge for yourself; (4) is the same as (5).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\subst}{sO{}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \left(#3\right)%
    \right|_{#4}
  }{%
    \mathopen{#2(}#3\mathclose{#2)}#2|_{#4}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\subst{\exp(x)}{x=0}             \\[1ex]
\subst{\exp(x)^{(i)}}{x=0}       \\[1ex]
\subst[\big]{\exp(x)^{(i)}}{x=0} \\[1ex]
\subst[\Big]{\exp(x)^{(i)}}{x=0} \\[1ex]
\subst*{\exp(x)^{(i)}}{x=0}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

You see that `\subst` can take an optional argument for the size of the delimiters around the main formula and, accordingly, the size of the vertical line. With `\subst*` you get automatic sizing (don't overuse it).

Note: `twocolumn` is just to make a smaller picture.

[image]

In the particular example you show, (2) seems perfectly good to my eye; possibly (3) can be used, but (4) and (5) have too big delimiters.